# What may be...is

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Taken from the Barron's SAT prep book:

> What may be the world's largest rodent is the capybara, a water loving mammal found throughout much of South America.

According to the answers this is a grammatically correct sentence, though it just looks and sounds very wrong to me, and I'm pretty sure I've never seen anything resembling this structure before.

My question is what are the benefits (if there are any) of such a sentence to this one:

> The world's largest rodent may be the capybara, a water loving mammal found throughout much of South America.

Comment: *Better* and *grammatical* are oblique if not orthogonal; which are you asking about?

Comment: I think any summary of "benefits/drawbacks" here is Primarily Opinion-based. As it happens, with no other context to skew things, I personally prefer the prosody of the original citation, though in a *specific* context I might prefer an alternative such as OP's rephrasing. But both what I said there and OP's *"it just looks and sounds very wrong to me"* are opinions. There is no possible "right answer".

Comment: @TimLymington If they aren't the same, I would be grateful to know how and why.

Comment: "Benefits" and "good" include such things as rhythm, clarity, and simplicity: they are, as FF said, largely subjective. Whether the sentence is grammatical (it is) depends on whether it follows the rules. If SATs only measure the latter, you probably shouldn't focus on how it sounds at present.

Comment: I suspect that it’s actually a water-loving mammal. Whether its acts of love are also aquatic is a different matter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could you provide a context that will "skew things" in either direction and explain why is it so?

Comment: The SAT sentence is better because it assumes that everyone in the world (or at least everyone reading the sentence) is wondering what the world's largest rodent is; thus its wording draws the reader into the question as if its answer is of vital importance. The second sentence is underwheleming; it states a probable fact in a humdrum manner.

Comment: @idanp: I'm not going to go overboard providing full contexts favouring one or the other (especially not within the confines of a comment). But I would just mention that apart from the "prosody" aspect, to me the original version more strongly implies that the capybara is *the largest rodent we currently know of* (but we haven't necessarily yet catalogued *all* rodents, so that statement may turn out not to be true at some point in the future). The rephrased version more strongly implies that *the author doesn't know* (but perhaps other people already do know with absolute certainty).

Comment: @CarSmack: That's another good point (which you posted as I was composing my own comment). But collectively, all such perspectives are really just a matter of LitCrit/personal opinion. I closevoted as POB, but if we'd had the option to migrate to [writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) I'd have gone for that. It's an interesting question - but it just seems Off Topic here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, that's not *necessarily* opinion based. It's a grammatical information packaging question. The cause of the unusual phrasing is a cleft construction. The 'benefits' as it were are the reasons why speakers use this construction and the 'grammatical' constraints on doing so. (To do with speaker old versus speaker new information, scope and focus). A bit too difficult for me at this time of the night, but someone else may be able to give a good detailed answer, useful to other readers I feel. The relative clause aficionados  will start sniffing round this soon enough!

Comment: The sentence is grammatically and idiomatically correct. Whether it's an appropriate way of phrasing the statement depends upon the context in which it appears. It's somewhat more stylish and may engage the experienced reader more strongly, at the cost of being harder to read for those who aren't as familiar with the language and its stylistic/poetic forms. (Plus @FumbleFingers' comments upon subtle shadings of emphasis.)

Comment: @Araucaria: I'm no expert on this level of text analysis, but it seems to me the "non-cleft" construction would start with *The capybara* in both cases, so I don't see how this "causes" unusual phrasing in either the original or OP's rephrasing. The relative clause *(a water loving mammal found ... America)* still follows the noun, but the relevant "speaker new" info *(may be the world's largest rodent)* would then come at the end rather than the beginning. But it's still POB/stylistic preference whether and why one might make *any* of these rearrangements.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We like to put new information at the end of the sentence - and at the end of the intonational phrase or clause. This is where the focus of the sentence is. So if we want to present *Capybara* as an important new theme in the text, but it would normally be in Subject position (where we like to see old material) then we use some construction to catapult it to the end where it will take focus. This is particularly useful if the 'subject' is very long, as it is here.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what are the benefits (if there are any) of such a
>   sentence

I can't think of any other than *Tone.*

The first is describing *that which may be* the largest rodent, and the second is simply telling you that the largest rodent *may be* the capybara.

As you pointed out, the sentences have the same meaning.

To me, the first conjures images of poetry and story-telling (... *what may well be the greatest adventure of them all, was a night when..*), while the second is less interesting but sounds more informative.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale behind this structure is to provide **Emphasis & Explanation**.

If we break down the sentence by the comma into two parts.

Part 1

What maybe the **largest/strongest/smallest/quickest**....

This part provides an emphasis on the extent to which the object is described.

Part 2

..... , a very **charming/loving/hateful**...throughout **someplace**.

This part provides a detailed explanation to the previously mentioned object.